# Unable to read newline \n character from console

Tags: python, regex, linux

I need to read a file from another Linux pc using `cat` like below

```
conf = other_linux.execute('cat xxx.conf')
```

conf will contain the contents of xxx.conf

```
peer 1 handler PEER_1
peer 2 handler PEER_2
peer 2 handler PEER_2
*************
----------------
```

I wrote the following regular expression to replace the whole peer configuration

```
re.sub('((peer\s\d\s\S+\s\S+\n)+)','</peer>',conf)
```

The above regular expression works fine if I read the conf from file directly, but it is not working when I read it using the `cat` command

Please provide some alternate as this is unable to read newline characters

Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between the strings when you read the file directly and when you read it using cat? Can you post the `repr` output of both strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used follwoing regex to fix the issue

```
((peer\s\d\s\S+\s\S+\r+\n+)+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
re.sub('((^peer\s\d\s\S+\s\S+$)+)','</peer>',conf, flags = re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the quick response 

I tried using above equation getting following error TypeError: sub() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags' even i tried using following line its not preplacing the node sentences re.sub('((^peer\s\d\s\S+\s\S+$)+)','</peer>',conf, re.MULTILINE)

Comment: Sorry it may work i am using older version of python which is 2.4 .. i must have to use this version ..for normal text file my regex is working fine but when i read from the console i am unable to replace using same reg ex

Comment: Surely the problem is that the console does not return \n but some character as \r.